React Native iOS Build Error: 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code' on macOS Sequoia
I am using macOS Sequoia 15.1.0 with Xcode 16.1 to run a React Native iOS app. However, when I attempt to build the app, I encounter the following error:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
This issue occurs not only with my existing project but also with a newly created React Native project.
What I Have Tried:
I have spent the past two weeks trying various solutions from Stack Overflow and GitHub discussions, but none have resolved the problem. Here are the steps I have already tried:
Reinstalled Xcode and ensured it is updated to version 16.1.
Updated CocoaPods to the latest version (pod --version outputs 1.16.2).
Cleared the derived data using xcodebuild clean and removed the DerivedData folder.
Installed dependencies again with pod install in the ios directory.
Attempted to run the app directly via Xcode instead of the CLI.
Verified that Homebrew is updated (brew --version outputs 4.4.5).
Tried running react-native run-ios with a freshly created project.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I am unable to proceed with my development.
Environment Details:
macOS Version: Sequoia 15.1.0
Xcode Version: 16.1
CocoaPods Version: 1.16.2
Homebrew Version: 4.4.5
React Native Version: (Specify the version here, e.g., 0.72.x)

The issue you're facing might be related to the NODE_BINARY path in your Xcode configuration. I've encountered this problem before, and here's how I resolved it:

Verify the NODE_BINARY Path
Run the following command in your terminal to find the correct path to your Node.js binary:


which node


Check and Update .xcode.env.local
The .xcode.env.local file might be hidden in Xcode. To reveal hidden files, press Command + Shift + . (dot) in Finder. Locate the file and open it.

If the NODE_BINARY path in .xcode.env.local doesn't match the path from the terminal, update it to the correct path you just copied.

Clean Build Folder

After updating the NODE_BINARY path, clean your build folder to ensure there are no residual errors:
In Xcode, go to Product > Clean Build Folder (Shift + Command + K).

Rebuild the Project

